# Finding a single path from any node on a graph to a specific node

Tags: java

Some more background on the question.

Line 1 from A, goes to B. Line 2 from A goes to C.
Line 1 from B, goes to A. Line 2 from B goes to C.
Line 1 from C, goes to B. Line 2 from C goes to A.

Suppose you are lost at one of the stations A, B, or C. Independent of 
where you are, if you take line 2, and then line 1, you always end up at station
B. Having a path that takes everyone to the same place is called a meeting path.
We are interested in finding a meeting path which consists of a fixed set of 
instructions like, 'take line 1, then line 2,' etc. It is possible that you might
visit a station multiple times. It is also possible that such a path might not exist.

I was thinking of using a Depth First Search on the graph to find each node. However because you can repeat nodes I was not sure when I should stop the search and say that there is no path.

Is there a better way to finding paths in a cyclical Directed graph than DFS?

Once I have a given path to test this is my current implementation.

```
public static int calculate(int[][] n, List<Integer> list){
    boolean flag = false;
    int list_counter = 0;
    mapEven.clear();
    mapOdd.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i<n.length;i++){
        int item = list.get(0);
        mapOdd.put(i, 1);

    }
    for(int x = 0; x < list.size() && !flag;x++){
        for(int i = 0; i < n.length ; i++){
            int station = path(n,i,list.get(x));
            if (station == -1){
                continue;
            }
            int old_station_amount;
            if(x%2==1){
                old_station_amount = mapEven.getOrDefault(i,0);
                mapOdd.put(station, old_station_amount+mapOdd.getOrDefault(station,0));
            }else{
                 old_station_amount = mapOdd.getOrDefault(i,0);
                mapEven.put(station, old_station_amount+mapEven.getOrDefault(station,0));
            }
        }
        if(x%2==1){
            mapEven.clear();
        }else{
            mapOdd.clear();
        }
        if(mapEven.values().contains((Integer) n.length) ||mapOdd.values().contains((Integer) n.length)){
            return -1;
        }
    }
    if(mapEven.values().contains((Integer) n.length) ||mapOdd.values().contains((Integer) n.length)){
        return -1;
    }else{
        return -3;
    }
}
```

Comment: The graph is directed or undirected ?

Comment: I forgot to mention it is a directed graph